# Excel Generation in android using Apache poi

Tags: java, android, excel, apache

I am using Apache poi in my android application for generating excel. When i tried to use  sheet.autoSizeColumn((short) 1) my application crashed with following errors.

Could not find class 'java.awt.font.TextLayout', referenced from method org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getCellWidth

Could not find class 'java.awt.font.TextLayout', referenced from method org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getColumnWidth
Is there any method for using the sheet,autoSizeColumn or any alternative. Please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the package `awt` is not included in Android, so if Apache poi uses it, you can't use it in Android.

Comment: is there any alternative for the same?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But I never tried editing Office docs in Android, so there might be.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is [JWord](http://www.independentsoft.de/jword). Works on Android and does not use AWT.